# Why does Average Log Likelihood

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, expectation

The average log likelihood $$L(W,X) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{1}^{N} log(p(x_n;W))$$ as defined by the authors in http://www.gatsby.ucl.ac.uk/aistats/fullpapers/217.pdf (first equation, first page, right column).

So far, so good.

Then the author(s) go on to say that $$L(W,X) = 
\sum_{1}^{N} \delta(x-x_n)log(p(x_n;W))$$.

I don't see why this is true.

Comment: I think you are missing a $(1/N)$ in front of the second equation. By the way, that's not what the authors say.